# Identifying Sorting Method in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I wrote the following code while exploring sorting algorithms, but I'm unsure about the specific sorting method it represents. Can someone help me identify it?

```
a = [64, 25, 12, 22, 11]
sorted_lis=[]

while not len(a)==0:
    sorted_lis.append(min(a))
    a.remove(min(a))

print(sorted_lis)
```

Appreciate any suggestions and insights into the sorting technique used in this code. Also if there are more efficient ways to achieve the same result, feel free to share your recommendations.

Comment: It doesn't have a name because it's your code (and it's very unnecessarily inefficient, even as a O(n^2) )

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).
If you want to know what existing algorithm this matches, you need to carefully step through a site that describes a variety of classic sorting algorithms, and see which matches the code you wrote.  This is not a Stack Overflow task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no algorithm in which we remove element but we can say it as selection sort because every time we are selecting minimum element from a list and in selection sort we do same thing.

Comment: According to Wikipaedia insertion sort deletes the entry from the source list. "At each iteration, insertion sort removes one element from the input data, finds the location it belongs within the sorted list, and inserts it there." Both insertion and selection sort are O(N^2) which is pretty bad

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort). This sort is really bad - it's O(N^2), you probably want to try to find a different sort algorithm

Comment: This is a selection sort, not an insertion sort.

Comment: The element is moved move the original list to a new list, rather than being moved within the same list. Therefore it is insertion sort. Please provide your reasoning if you disagree

Comment: You've misunderstood the identifying features of insertion sort and selection sort. Insertion sort takes an element and *inserts* it into its spot in the result, shifting elements. Selection sort searches an unsorted collection to *select* the next element to append to the result.

Comment: Both insertion sort and selection sort can be implemented to operate with two lists or with one list. The number of lists used does not distinguish an insertion sort from a selection sort.

Comment: I have looked again and it does appear to be insertion sort. Sorry, I haven't used insertion or selection sort since the 90s